# Perform CRUD via javascrip in an existing database that is only accessible via vpn

Tags: mysql, next.js, ssh, prisma, remote-server

I am working on a project using Next.js that involves fetching some data from a companies existing database. They have provided me with following details.

```
SoftEther VPN 4.43 Build 9799 Beta (August 31, 2023):
HostName
Port 
HUB
ID
PASSWORD

SSH:
HOSTNAME 
UserID
PASSWORD
PORT 22

DATABASE:
HOSTNAME 
UserID 
PASSWORD
PORT
```

I have successfully accessed their database using MySQL Workbench. But I am unable to understand How can I develop the project?

Thanks for your help :)
Happy coding…

Earlier I was using ssh2 for tunneling and port forwarding and mysql2 for query generation. But now there is another thing in between VPN. How am I supposed to proceed further?